# Draw line within CCSprite bounds cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, line, draw, ccsprite

I am developing game in cocos2d which contains CCSprite of apple,mango and banana shapes. Now i want user to draw line ( i guess through CCMoionStreak) within selected CCSprite (apple,mango or banana).

I have below question:

How can i achieve this draw line functionality? As User can only draw in selected shape.

Please help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I've understood you correctly but I think you could use something like this:

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(sprite rect, location))
    {
     do your drawing
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to happen if the user starts outside the sprite or ends outside the sprite.  If this is like the ninja fruit game, detect where the swipe enters and exits the sprite (or approximate if the swipe is too fast).  Otherwise, just check that the start and stop points are in the rect.

In either case, use ccDrawline between those points.